# Using union to do a crosstab query

Tags: database

I have a table which has the following structure :

```
id    key data
1     A   10
1     B   20
1     C   30
```

I need to write a query so that i get these keys as columns and the value as rows.

Eg :

```
  id A  B  C
  1 10 20 30
```

I have tried using union and case but i get 3 rows for instead of one

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use case and grouping.

Comment: You might be able to use a `PIVOT` if your DBMS supports it -- please tell us which one you're using.

Comment: oracle db..i tried using case and group by bu ti get 3 rows with null in 2 columns...                                           <pre> id  A    B      C
1  10   null  null
1  null  20   null
1  null null  30</pre>

Comment: @Nikhil. Did you managed to make it work?

Comment: UNION is not appropriate since you want to pivot data. Is this Access database? Why not use a CROSSTAB query?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do this is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "id", 
   (SELECT "data" FROM Table1 WHERE "key" = 'A') AS "A",
   (SELECT "data" FROM Table1 WHERE "key" = 'B') AS "B",
   (SELECT "data" FROM Table1 WHERE "key" = 'C') AS "C"
FROM Table1
```

Or you can use a PIVOT:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT "id", "key", "data" FROM Table1)
PIVOT (
  MAX("data") 
    FOR ("key") IN ('A', 'B', 'C'));
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe082/16)</kbd>