# Collect Option Group values and insert values into a Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a form with several toggle buttons. I want to be able to toggle each button for a specific value and use the selected values as an `insert into` another table.

Form input working, tables and junction works, form Subdatasheet with query is updateable and shows the relevant fields

```
Select * from FRAMEQUERY(as Boolean) WHERE Value = True

INSERT INTO ORDERDETAILS
```

Need some code help to collect the values and insert them.

Answer (score 0):

Since the fields that are to be inserted are dependent upon the state of the form controls, you will need to iterate over the relevant form controls and construct an appropriate SQL statement which may then be executed using methods such as `DoCmd.RunSQL` or `CurrentDb.Execute`.

I would suggest iterating over the controls on your form, and, for each control, if the control is selected, append the corresponding field name to the `insert into` and `select` portions of the SQL statement.

For example, in **pseudocode**, this might be something like:

```
strFld = ""
strVal = ""
for each control on form
    if control.value = true then
        strFld = strFld & "YourFieldName, "
        strVal = strVal & "YourFieldValue, "
    end if
next control

if strFld <> "" then
    strFld = left(strFld, len(strFld)-2) 
    strVal = left(strVal, len(strVal)-2)
    strSQL = "insert into YourTable (" & strFld & ") values (" & strVal & ")"
end if
```

Comment: Control collection includes labels and other non-data controls which do not have Value property. Code will need a conditional to test for type of control. Assuming control name is same as field name, concatenation would reference control Name and Value properties. `& control.Name & ","` and `& control.Value & ","`.

Comment: An alternative is to assign similar names to toggle buttons - Tgl1, Tgl2, etc. Then in a `For n = 1 to x` loop dynamically build control reference `Me("Tgl" & n).Value`. Does complicate grabbing associated field name. The respective field name can be in toggle button Tag property `strFld = strFld & Me("Tgl" & n).Tag & ","`.

Comment: UNION is not appropriate since you want to pivot data. Is this Access database? Why not use a CROSSTAB query? – June7 Dec 29 '17 at 21:23 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492418/using-union-to-do-a-crosstab-query this was your answer to a similar post, how can I implement this or a combination